# Select last rows in MySQL and stop on matching condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing user login data:

```
------------------------------------
| ip          | timestamp | result |
------------------------------------
| 12.34.56.78 | 12345671  | 0      |
| 12.34.56.78 | 12345672  | 0      |
| 12.34.56.78 | 12345673  | 1      |
| 12.34.56.78 | 12345674  | 0      |
```

`result=0` means login failure, `result=1` means success.

My goal is to select the last rows of the table where `result=0` (order by timestamp desc), stopping selection at the first `result=1` row. In the shown example, query should return  the last row only.

I've tryied the following

```
SELECT * FROM attempts WHERE ip="12.34.56.78" AND result=0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

but it returns all the rows with `result=0` (for the required IP). How can I modify it to stop on first `result=1` match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this by using a cross join to get the max `timestamp` where result is 1 and then compare it with outer query's timestamp

```
select a.* 
from attempts a
cross join(
  select max(`timestamp`) max_time
  from attempts
  where result=1 
  and ip='12.34.56.78' 
  ) t
WHERE a.ip='12.34.56.78'
and a.result=0 
and a.timestamp > t.max_time
```

I have added some demo data in fiddle with result 0 and greater timestamp from the last result = 1 row's timestamp,It will return the rows which have greater timestamp and result is 0 comparing to the timestamp where result was 1

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/50fed/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
*
from
attempts
where timestamp < (select timestamp from attempts where ip='12.34.56.78' and result = 1)
and ip='12.34.56.78' and result = 0
order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71c1d4/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "limit" command in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM attempts WHERE ip="12.34.56.78" AND result=0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1;
```

It will return the last entry matching the criteria.

Comment: This is wrong as it does not consider the time at which result was 1